# SDL game loop is dropping frames because of SDL_GL_SwapWindow

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, game-engine

I'm just trying to make an empty game loop that doesn't lag!

My loop does basically nothing, yet sometimes it lags enough to drop frames (I'm trying to run at 60fps)

I traced the problem to `SDL_GL_SwapWindow`. I made sure vsync is turned off.

Most of the time `SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);` takes <1ms. But sometimes it can take long enough to drop frames. Is this normal? I can't believe my raw C++ empty game loop is sometimes dropping frames!
[image]

My code doesn't do anything interesting, I've tried tweaking it quite a bit, but I've seen no improvement. You can see it all here http://pastebin.com/GpLAH8SZ

P.S. I'm on a decent gaming desktop!

Comment: You're measuring `SDL_PollEvent`, `glClearDepth`, `glClear`, *and* `SDL_GL_SwapWindow`, so you can't tell which is the important factor.

Comment: @molbdnilo You're right, I used to have it measuring only SDL_GL_SwapWindow and it was just as bad (I've been testing a bunch of different things and I forgot to put it back)

Comment: Disabling vsync isn't really a good idea, especially when benchmarking on tiny workload. 1ms isn't a problem, missing vsync timer is (but then again, only if there is no external interference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is the OS, which may not schedule you 100% of time.

You can change the [msdn : process class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms686219(v=vs.85).aspx). But there is going to be intervals where windows does not have resources to keep running your code, and keep running.

Comment: What do you mean exactly (I'm on Windows 10) Is there anyway to request priority scheduling or something

Comment: closing chrome and all other programs helped a lot (idk why I didn't try this earlier), also changing the priority seems to have helped too, so I think you're right!